# step by step hello world in assembly for mac OS

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am struggling quite a lot with assembly for mac os (x86_64 architecture). I would like to walk you through the explanation of a hello world program and I would appreciate if you could give me your feedback with suggestions and explanations: having said that let’s jump into the code.

## Hello world program

Never felt the pain of an Hello world before.
So, this is the code that I have copied and pasted from the internet:

```
global _main 
section .text

_main:
   mov rax, 0x2000004
   mov rdi, 1
   mov rsi, str
   mov rdi str.len
   syscall

   mov rax, 0x2000001
   xor rdi, rdi 
   syscall

section .data
str: “Hello world”, 
.len: equ $ - str
```

So let me embarass myself:

1. global _main is telling basically the linker where to start if I am not mistaken
2. Section .text is telling the OS (I guess) that this is the beginning of the actual program.
3. _main if I am not wrong is a function and this seems to be the notation for functions
4. mov rax, 0x2000004 : I do not understand what this thing does. I looked up on the internet how a syscall works and it basically needs a file code (I think this is the 1 on the next line), a pointer to a buffer (where is exactly this buffer, i think points to the first byte of my string) and the length in bytes of the piece of text (in this case .len). My question is when I need to write something, how does this hexidecimal business work and what is the actual job of the mov rax instruction.
5. mov rdi, 1: I am still not getting what is actually happening. We need a 1 to set output to stdout, but what is the actual function of this instruction, where is this 1 going, what is happening behind the scenes.
6. Then we have this str.len which I do not quite understand, what is this .len notation?I get that this gives the size of the string, but how can we write it like this?
7. syscall: this function seems like black magic, and I know that the Os is doing some dirty tricks but I am pretty ignorant of OS’s and so I can’t get what is this thing doing.
8. mov rax, 0x2000001: now we need to exit the program, again why do we need to load into a register this hex number (yes I know this is the command to exit but again, what is actually happening).
9. xor rdi, rdi: this is probably the only bit that I get, we are setting to 0 the content of the rdi register by xoring the same two values.
10. syscall: this is black magic
11. str: “Hello World”: I get this :)
12. .len: I do not understand this .notation. I think that $ means “address of here” or at least this is something I looked up, and I think it is correct.

Comment: Are you sure this works, as you write 1 and str.len into rdi

Comment: Does that trailing comma in `str: “Hello world”, ` produce a terminating zero? Or does this fail to assemble? Unless maybe you're not even using an actual assembler?

Comment: You probably meant `mov rdx, str.len`.  The 3rd arg for system calls goes in RDX, the first arg is already in RDI.  The code inside the kernel that you "call" with `syscall` can only look at the current state of registers when it gets control, so anything you overwrote before that is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No, that just exports the symbol.
2. No, that tells the assembler which section to put the following stuff into. `.text` is a default section for code.
3. No, that's a label. Function entry points are usually denoted by labels, but not all labels are functions.
4. On MacOS the value `0x2000004` is the code that specifies you want a `write` system call. The OS will look in `rax` to determine what the caller wants. All system services have a code. You can imagine the OS doing something like `if (rax == 0x2000004) do_write(rdi, rsi, rdx);`
5. `rdi` is a register. You know the registers, right? Similarly to point #4 above, the OS once it determined you wanted a `write` will check `rdi` for the destination file descriptor.
6. `str.len` is just a label syntax. The value is defined at the bottom. This should be loaded into `rdx` not `rdi` though.
7. It transfers control to the OS. Which then look at the contents of the registers and performs the action requested. The OS is just code, albeit privileged.

As for (12), yes, `$` is the current location, which is the end of the string. So subtracting the start of the string will give you the length. The leading dot is just a special label which instructs the assembler to prefix it with the nearest previous non-local label, in this case `str`. So that's equivalent to writing `str.len`.

Comment: Basically you do `write(1, "Hello World", 11); exit(0);`, `syscall` is "just" a fancy call, that goes from the userspace into the kernel and back again

Comment: Thanks very much man! Great explanation for a beginner like me in particular the analogy for understanding the system call :P. This is the best resource I have found so far. Do you know by any chance some at least moderately complete resources for x86_64 architecture?

Comment: It won't be the answer for everybody, but the C compiler is the best resource for learning assembly

Comment: @not_here_to_play: Intel and AMD both publish complete manuals for the x86-64 ISA.  Of course if you actually mean for writing user-space code under an existing kernel like MacOS, with existing ABIs, that would be a totally separate thing that CPU vendor manuals don't mention at all.

Comment: Re: `if (rax == 0x2000004) do_write(rdi, rsi, rdx);` - in MacOS, the high bits are flags that specify which table of system calls, and the low bits are an integer index into a table of call numbers.  Presumably an array of function pointers, [like Linux uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46087731/224132), although Linux and MacOS differ slightly in their system-call ABI.  (Error return indicated by CF=1 on MacOS vs. RAX >= -4095ULL on Linux.)